# Proper space between hyperref textfield name and text box

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref

I use LaTeX occassionally, but not sure how to get the `hypperref` text fields to tab up properly.  I got sick of using OpenOffice/LibreOffice to convert out PDF's that suck and have poorly done text boxes.  The Ooo document looks like so.

[image]

And this is the LaTeX doc I am working with below, and what it currently looks like.  I want to get something with similar clean, tabbed spacing.  Any pointers?  I tried scanning the hyperref docs, but I did not find what I was looking for or Google did not real smile at me today.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
pdfauthor = {My Name},
pdftitle = {Blah blah blah},
pdfsubject = {Blah blah blah},
pdfkeywords = {Blah, blah, blah},
pdfcreator = {LaTeX with hyperref package},
pdfproducer = {TexWorks 0.4.3 r857 via MikTeX 2.9}}

\def \textfieldwidth {3in}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \TextField[name=EmployeeName,width=\textfieldwidth]{Employee Name:} \\\\
    \TextField[name=EmployeeEmail,width=\textfieldwidth]{Employee E-mail:} \\\\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to change things. The `\AdjustSize` macro uses `\makebox` to enclose the label text in a box of width specified in `\LabelWidth` so that all the labels are the same size. If you have larger labels you can adjust that setting.

If you do not want to specify a fixed width you could compute the `\LabelWidth` if you know the largest text by commenting out the `\setlength...` and using the `\settowidth...`.

Here is the MWE with the fixed width setting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
pdfauthor = {My Name},
pdftitle = {Blah blah blah},
pdfsubject = {Blah blah blah},
pdfkeywords = {Blah, blah, blah},
pdfcreator = {LaTeX with hyperref package},
pdfproducer = {TexWorks 0.4.3 r857 via MikTeX 2.9}}

\def\textfieldwidth{3.5in}%

\newlength{\LabelWidth}%
\setlength{\LabelWidth}{1.3in}%
%\settowidth{\LabelWidth}{Employee E-mail:}%  Specify the widest text here.

% Optional first parameter here specifies the alignment of
% the text within the \makebox.  Default is [l] for left 
% alignment. Other options are [r] and [c] for right and center
\newcommand*{\AdjustSize}[2][l]{\makebox[\LabelWidth][#1]{#2}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \TextField[name=EmployeeName,width=\textfieldwidth]{\AdjustSize[l]{Employee Name:}} \\\\
    \TextField[name=EmployeeEmail,width=\textfieldwidth]{\AdjustSize{Employee E-mail:}} \\\\
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, I will check this out tomorrow morning at work. Thanks a million.